# Execute two functions without .then()

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Currently I have this code:

```
client.clearStore()
  .then(() => someFunction())
  .catch(e => logger.error('error', e));
```

It works okay but I have a problem on testing with `.then()`, so I wondered if there is an another way to execute both `client.clearStore()` and `someFunction()` but having finished `client.clearStore()` that returns a promise.

Comment: Seems like an X/Y problem.  What is your testing problem related to `then()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const someFunction = await client.clearStore();

    someFunction();
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error('error', e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I'm using an IIFE here, but obviously you can just assign and call this as you would any other function, just make sure to prefix it with the async.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `await` keyword like this

```
(async () => {
    await client.clearStore();
    someFunction()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    await client.clearStore();
    someFunction()
} catch (e) {
    logger.error('error', e)
}
```

But solution with 'then' looks much better to me and executes asynchronously (theoretically, main thread is being executed while we're waiting for 'clearStore' to finish). I guess you have problems with mocking 'clearStore' to return a promise?

Comment: Yes... exactly that. That's why I changed to await. Now it works but I would like to use the first code. I get an `undefined` at  `client.clearStore()`. I have mocked `client` but don't know why in the test says that is undefined

Comment: Then I suggest you could re-phrase your question or create a new one. Unfortunately we can't see your test setup in the attached code.